# Is it possible to make the voice of user instead of inbuilt voice in TTS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, voice

We have Text to speech feature wherein a set of voices and different pitch, male/female voices are present.
Similarly we do have voice recognition available in many devices and PCs.
Is there any possibility that a system makes use of voice of the User to speak instead of inbuilt default voices?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is theoretically possible it is most likely unpractical. There are basically two types of artificial voices: fully synthetic and sample based.

1. If your TTS voice is fully synthetic then it can only be influenced by certain parameters such as pitch and speed. Your best approach is to try and estimate all parameters from your input speech.
2. If your TTS voice is sample based then you could try to collect enough speech from the user to construct a whole new dataset. Usually you need every possible [diphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphone), which can take a long time to collect unless you have the user utter some text specifically to collect these. Then your engine needs to be able to accept the speech parts and construct a new voice from them.

In both cases the result still won't be very convincing unless you can also mimic the user's prosody and specific pronunciation. If your TTS and recognition modules aren't developed by yourself or extensible then you are likely out of luck since most software don't allow new voices to be built at runtime.